# Using same ruby block is now throwing errors

Tags: ruby

Consider this block of code:

```rb
f = File.new('test')
f.each_line { |line|
  if line =~ /@b/ then
    x = line
  end
}
y = x[/<(.*)>/,1]
```

This is `f`:

```
@a <1,2,3>
@b <'whatever'>
@c <['x','y','z']
@d <1.1>
```

and
Originally, this block of code was working, returning `y` as `'whatever'`, but is now throwing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        4: from C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/irb.cmd:31:in `<main>'
        3: from C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/irb.cmd:31:in `load'
        2: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/irb-1.0.0/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        1: from (irb):10
NameError (undefined local variable or method `x' for main:Object)
```

Any suggestions?

> P.S.
>
> This is being run directly through irb

Comment: What statement is on line 10 ('10' being from your error message)? You need to pay careful attention to error messages; often the pinpoint the problem.

Comment: You are aware that if multiple lines match `@b` then `x` will only represent the last one correct?

Comment: If you want all matches you could do something like: `lines = File.foreach('test').grep(/@b/)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x` is being defined in the local context of the block, and once the context of the block is left it is no longer defined. So variable `x` needs to be defined outside the context of the block:

```rb
x = nil
f = File.new('test')
f.each_line { |line|
  if line =~ /@b/ then
    x = line
  end
}
y = x[/<(.*)>/,1]
```

Comment: You might show how you are using the initial value of `x` in the event that no line matches `/@b/`: `y = x.nil? ? nil : x[/<(.*)>/,1]`.

Answer (score 2):

Scope.
Define x, then run in irb, and note that it works…

```
x = 'not in scope'
f = File.new('test')
f.each_line { |line|
  if line =~ /@b/ then
    x = line
  end
}
y = x[/<(.*)>/,1]
```